# How can I make Apache wait for images to be fully written to the storage drive before serving them?

Tags: apache, images, apache2, download

I'm using `fswebcam` to take pictures from my webcam and write them to `/var/www` so that anybody can view them from my website.

The problem is that my server is a Raspberry Pi with a slow SD card. It takes several seconds to write the image to the SD card. If a user requests the image while it is still being written, they'll get a half-finished version of the image:

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to make Apache wait for an image to be fully written before it serves it?

Comment: How often are images saved? Are you always overwriting the same image or is there a timestamp incorporated into the filename? How is the HTML page generated that displays the image?

Comment: Without an example of how you are doing this it is difficult to provide an answer. The solution will almost certainly be a Bash [conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) or a specific [list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) like this: Take photo > write photo to card > `mv` or `cp` newly written photo to Apache directory to be served from. `cp next.jpg current.jpg` or something basic like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving a file within the same disk is a very quick (nearly instantaneous) operation.   Instead of saving them directly to `www` save them to a different directory on the same disk where Apache can't see them.   Then when they are fully saved, move them into place in `www`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and it worked perfectly. Thanks to you and Tom Brossman for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about apache but I think some scripting language should be able to detect if a file is being written (perhaps using file handles?)

You can then wait for it to finish and serve the file.